# How to change the layout when we touch wrong item?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I need to run this app as follow -> : if I touch correct item , `score+=5`, else change to `gameover.xml`

I don't know how to change activity to another layout?

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int tx = (int) event.getX();
    int ty = (int) event.getY();

    int i = 0;
    for (Element element : mElements) {
        if ((element.getmX() < tx && tx < element.getmX()
                + element.getWidth())
                && (element.getmY() < ty && ty < element.getmY()
                        + element.getHeight())) {

            ***if (mGarbagType == element.getGtype()) {

                score += 5;
            }else score-=5;***
            Log.v("DustmanGame", "Touch on:" + element.getGtype()
                    + "Score : 5");

            mElements.remove(i);
            mElementNumber = mElements.size();

            mGarbagType = randomGarbage();

            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to change activity to another layout

In your `else {}` block simply launch a new Activity with `startActivity()` to use `gameover.xml` or call `setContentView(R.layout.gameover)` in this Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Have different layout in your xml, use View.GONE or View.VISIBLE depends on your requirement